# How to return array of char?

Tags: c, alsa

I want to return char array from snd_mixer_selem_get_id function:

```
char* alsa_get_channel_name( void )
{
    int err;
    snd_mixer_selem_id_t *sid;
    snd_mixer_elem_t *elem;

    if ((err = snd_mixer_open (&handle, 0)) < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "mixer: open error: %s\n", snd_strerror(err));
    }
    if ((err = snd_mixer_attach (handle, card)) < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "mixer: attach error: %s\n", snd_strerror(err));
    }
    if ((err = snd_mixer_selem_register (handle, NULL, NULL)) < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "mixer: register error: %s\n", snd_strerror(err));
    }
    if ((err = snd_mixer_load (handle)) < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "mixer: load error: %s\n", snd_strerror(err));
    }

    snd_mixer_selem_id_alloca(&sid);

    for (elem = snd_mixer_first_elem(handle); elem; elem = snd_mixer_elem_next(elem)) {
            if ((!snd_mixer_selem_is_active(elem))
                    continue;

            snd_mixer_selem_get_id(elem, sid);
            const char *name = snd_mixer_selem_id_get_name(sid);
            if (name)
                sprintf(name, sizeof(name), "%s", snd_mixer_selem_get_name(elem));
    }
    snd_mixer_close(handle);

    return name;
}
```

I don't know how to write line sprintf(name, sizeof(name), "%s", snd_mixer_selem_get_name(elem)); to return channel name.

Thanks

Comment: Note you are returning pointer of pointer what return type of function is (so it correct). But you are not returning pointer of char array. an I feel you won't return that.

Comment: for starters, your `name` is a `const char*`, not a `char **`, and they are *not* synonymous. Is there some reason you're not `malloc()`ing a result buffer, copying your results to it, and returning that? (i.e. returning a `char *`).

Comment: `return result;` however, you haven't gotten any space for that or put anything in there. You should really format your question better.

Answer (score 1):

Your call to `sprintf()` is wrongly specified. Check `man sprintf`, the the `sprintf()` function takes a pointer as first argument, and the second argument is supposed to be the format specifier. Perhaps you mean to use `snprintf()`?

- `name` is a `const char *`, meaning it's a pointer to `const char`, so you aren't allowed to write into it.
- `name` is a `const char *`, meaning it's a *pointer*. `sizeof(name)` will evaluate to the size of a pointer-to-char, not to `strlen(name) + 1`, which you seem to be assuming.
- `name` is a pointer that was returned from `snd_mister_selem_id_get_name()`. Are you even allowed to write into that? You appear to be trying to overwrite the "mixer simple element identifier" with the "name part of mixer simple element identifier" (and then return it). However, at the beginning your question says "I want to return char array from snd_mixer_selem_get_id function".

The simplest way to return "char array from snd_mixer_selem_get_id function" would be to just do `return snd_mixer_selem_get_name(elem)` instead of trying to `sprintf()` it into something... If there's a reason why you really need to return a copy of the string instead, you could `return`strdup(snd_mixer_selem_get_name(elem))`, and remember that the caller will be responsible for calling`free()` on the return value.

However, since your question is fairly unclear (and the ALSA documentation is almost as unclear as your question), I suggest that you rewrite your question explaining exactly what your ultimate goal here is, and try again.